# Modifying z axis position of a canvas and adapting it to camera

Tags: unity, c#

I have a camera with y rotation of 0.

And i have a canvas with position value of `(0f,76.29f,41.82f)`.
The size value of the canvas is `(194.1f,307.8f)`.
I want to modify the z value of the canvas to -10.

```
public Canvas textcanvas;
void Start () {
textcanvas.anchoredPosition = new Vector3 (0f, 24.5f, -10f);
}
```

But i get an error "error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Canvas' does not contain a definition for`anchoredPosition' and no extension method `anchoredPosition' of type`UnityEngine.Canvas' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?"

Also, when i succeed moving the canvas, does the size of it adapting to the camera automatically?

Comment: ((RectTransform)textcanvas.transform).anchoredPosition

Comment: @Draco18s: a one-liner answer is still worth sharing as an answer. ;) (Of course, adding a second line explaining why you can't access it from the canvas reference alone would be even better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`((RectTransform)textcanvas.transform).anchoredPosition`

The problem here is a very basic one: `Canvas` objects aren't `Transforms`. Transform objects are the only ones that contain position information, so you can't modify the position of the canvas by calling `textcanvas.anchoredPosition` because it doesn't exist there, you need to access the canvas's Transform: `textcanvas.transform.anchoredPosition`

However this won't work either, not directly, because there are two Transform classes:

- Transform (for most GameObjects)
- RectTransform (for most UI objects) which extends Transform

So we have to cast from one to the other, as the `GameObject.Transform` property is of type `Transform`, not `RectTransform` and `anchoredPosition` is a property of `RectTransform` and not `Transform`.  Hence the final solution:

`((RectTransform)textcanvas.transform).anchoredPosition`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the canvas to appear in front of a camera, you need to change the Canvas component to "Render Mode: Screen Space (Camera)" or "World Space" and then drag your camera into the canvas component.

If you want your menu to appear "transformed" I find the easiest thing to do is make an empty object under your canvas (I called it MenuTransform), and then place all your UI elements as children of that (like the panel in this example).  Then, you can transform all the elements at once.

[image: unity]